# Convert Image Type Data to XML/Plain Text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm working on `SSRS` Report.

I have the content with Data type `Image`. I want to convert it into `plain-text` or `XML`. Is it possible?

I am not providing the sample data as there is huge data. (Whole report content saving to image so we can understand)

Suggest me the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried below and working fine but appending extra string like this `ï»¿` to output.

*Used RIGHT() to chop off first 3 characters - working fine*

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX) ,ImageDataField))),
LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX) ,ImageDataField))))-3)
```

Comment: That's a UTF-8 BOM. `varchar` expects ASCII. `nvarchar` may fair slightly better, but I think it expects to be working with UCS-2.

Comment: so what should I do? can you please help me? I tried by using `NVARCHAR()` but still same output.

Comment: There's no simple answer. You've stored UTF-8 data but SQL Server doesn't understand that encoding. This may be fixable by a) updating whatever code is storing this data to not emit the UTF-8 BOM (It is, after all, optional, and not actually recommended) and then b) correcting the existing data to remove it.

Comment: okay thanks. BTW I am retrieving this data from report server catalog table. So I think there must be something to change this format while saving ssrs report.

Comment: If you know those three characters are always present at the beginning of the file and you cannot change the process that stores the images, you can chop off the first three characters in your select.

Answer (score 2):

This works from SQL Server Management Studio, when the current database is the ReportServer database.

```
-- given a NonRemitted_detail.rdl file that was deployed to a report server on path /Jacket Generator 
-- the contents can be found as XML with this:
SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)) AS rdl_file_content
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog]
    WHERE [Path] = N'/Jacket Generator/NonRemitted_detail'
```

Nearly identical. Whitespace between XML elements has been stripped. The opening XML declaration is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below,

```
CREATE TABLE #a (id IMAGE )

INSERT INTO #a VALUES('imagedata' )

SELECT CONVERT(IMAGE ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX) ,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX) ,ID))) AS  'TEXT TO IMAGE' FROM   #a

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX) ,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX) ,ID))) ' IMAGE TO TEXT ' FROM   #a

DROP TABLE #a
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried. Not giving proper data. Ouput of Image To Text is - `ï»¿<?xml v`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your images to base64 string using XML
if your table name is Images

```
select * from Images FOR XML PATH('Images')
```

out put will be like this

```
<Images>
  <ImageID>2</ImageID>
  <Img>/9j/4TfsRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAAAAGAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAKAAAAjAESAAMAAAABAAEAAA</Img>
</Images>
```